# Converting ALMA algorithm to javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithmic-trading, pine-script, cryptocurrency

I am trying to create a trading tool that connects to the Binance API and calculates various indicators and trades accordingly. I am using the ALMA and EMA indicators provided by TradingView. The settings of my ALMA are (30, 0.85, 6) with a period of 1h.

In the documentation of TradingView, I have found the algorithm for the ALMA calculation and it's the following:

```
pine_alma(series, windowsize, offset, sigma) =>
    m = floor(offset * (windowsize - 1))
    s = windowsize / sigma
    norm = 0.0
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to windowsize - 1
        weight = exp(-1 * pow(i - m, 2) / (2 * pow(s, 2)))
        norm := norm + weight
        sum := sum + series[windowsize - i - 1] * weight
    sum / norm
```

My tool is written in javascript, so I have translated it to the following:

```
function calculateALMA(series, windowsize, offset, sigma) {
    let m = Math.floor(offset * (windowsize - 1));
    let s = windowsize / sigma;
    let weight = 0.0;
    let norm = 0.0;
    let sum = 0.0;
    for (let i = 0; i < windowsize; i++) {
      console.log(i);
        weight = Math.exp(-1 * Math.pow(i - m, 2) / (2 * Math.pow(s, 2)));
        norm = norm + weight;
        sum = sum + (series[windowsize - i - 1].close * weight);
    }
    return (sum / norm);
}
```

'series' is an array with the 30 latest candlesticks for the 1h period. 
My problem is that the calculated value is not exactly the same as the value shown in the tradingview graph for the ALMA.
For example, my calculated ALMA for BTCUSDT is **9534.99**, while the ALMA on the graph is **9486.99**. 
The close values are the same in the graph and in the data I receive from binance, so I suspect my translation from pine-script to javascript has an error.

Any ideas where I went wrong?

Edit: Content of 'series' is something like this (with 30 items)

```
[ { openTime: 1564387200000,
    open: 9624.79,
    high: 9650,
    low: 9525.01,
    close: 9573.26,
    volume: 1155.847601,
    closeTime: 1564390799999 },
  { openTime: 1564390800000,
    open: 9573.64,
    high: 9584.98,
    low: 9395,
    close: 9494.08,
    volume: 2105.111588,
    closeTime: 1564394399999 },
  { openTime: 1564394400000,
    open: 9495.51,
    high: 9544,
    low: 9456.14,
    close: 9511.69,
    volume: 1056.144078,
    closeTime: 1564397999999 },
...
]
```

Comment: Mind providing a full example of the structure of the "series" object ?

Comment: I edited the question with the content of 'series'

Comment: I can see 1 strange difference - in original you are missing .close next to series[windowsize - i - 1] but do not know what it can do then.

Comment: xd, would you provide the entire object with the 30 items or run the original script with only the items that you provide and see if it results in a different value. If it's too long, use another website to share the JSON e.g https://justpaste.it

Comment: Tom, in the original script, the series is just an array of the close values. My series is an array of candlestick objects. Hence the .close needed in my array :-)

Comment: After 3+ years here in StackOverflow, one cannot be expected not to understand the core philosophy of MCVE-formulated problem. In Quant/Finance, it is common not to get the same indicator values, often due to different properties, how does a source-language / code-execution-platform get  processed the TimeSeries data-segment, during the executed algorithm-under-test and how does the same data-segment get processed inside the target-language / code-execution-platform. **Obviously,** the MCVE-formulated **problem must have the full-copy of** TimeSeries **data**. "Any ideas...?" does not help...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the issue...
My translation was working as it should. The issue was that I needed to reverse the array so the newest data was first.

In other words, when calling the function reverse the array for the `series` parameter:

`calculateALMA(series.reverse(), windowsize, offset, sigma)`

Comment: since `series.reverse()` will also mutate the `series` array, a non-destructive way to reverse it would be to write `[...series].reverse()` instead